# Deleting multiple rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I need to delete top 1000 rows in a datagridview.

```
delegate void DeleteRowsCallback(); 
    private static void Delete1KRows()
    {
        JSONTest form = (JSONTest)Application.OpenForms["JSONTest"];
        if (form.GridTestReport.InvokeRequired)
        {
            DeleteRowsCallback d = new DeleteRowsCallback(Delete1KRows);
            form.GridTestReport.Invoke(d);

        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
            {
                form.GridTestReport.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

            }
        }

    }
```

This deletes the rows but takes lot of time. Also the UI is non-responsive when the delete is in progress. Any better way to delete multiple rows.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the `DataGridView` in `Virtual` mode? How have you binded the data to the grid?

Comment: your gridview have datasource right? why don't u delete all records u want from it's data source, and then u can call gridview.databind() to refresh the ui, that way u don't need to remove gridview rows manually.

Comment: I am not binding the gridview. I am calling form.GridTestReport.Rows.Add(). I am not using Virtual mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not using any binding or virtual mode, everytime you remove a row, the entire grid is refreshed. It would be painfully slow.

As you are dealing with large amount of data, use `Virtual Mode` to efficietly update the grid.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx) MSDN link for more information. There is a [Walkhrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx) available. It takes little time to setup but once it is done it would much faster ane makes life easier.

Also see [Best Practices for Scaling the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx) to get the maximum out `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 1):

When DataGridView activities run slowly in my projects, it is usually because one or more columns are configured to auto-size, and this auto-sizing happens over the whole grid as each row is deleted. To prevent it, I use code similar to the following:

Before the mass deletion:

```
var autoSizeModes = grid.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>).ToDictionary(col => col, col => col.AutoSizeMode);
foreach (var column in autoSizeModes.Keys)
    column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
```

After the mass deletion:

```
foreach (var column in autoSizeModes)
    column.Key.AutoSizeMode = column.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is my working solution.
First delete the rows in database and then refill datagridview.
NOTE: I use database access (oledbcommand, oledbconnection, etc...), change for your connection.

```
try
{
    //connectDB is the procedure to connect to database:
    connectDB();
    //this delete first the selected rows in database, and then update datagrid
    int countRows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < countRows; i++)
    {
        int currentRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        //con.oledbcon is the conecction is the OleDbConnection procedure, miTable = name of your table
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM miTable WHERE Id=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), con.oledbcon);
        // delete from database
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // THIS IS THE KEY!!! deselect the last row selected to be able to delete the next row in the next loop
        dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Selected = false;
    }
    // all OK
    MessageBox.Show("Rows deleted!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //in case of error
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
finally
{
    //disconnectDB is the procedure to disconnect to database:
    disconnectDB();
    // and finally, refill datagrid again
    loaddatagrid();
}
```